# Owncloud doesn't run on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnupg, compatibility, keyrings, owncloud-client

Since I upgraded to 22.04 the Owncloud Client doesn't run or start anymore. I tried different methods of installing and even tride to run Owncloud as sudo from the terminal, no success.

Owncloud isn’t running on startup and doesn’t open when activating the application shortcut. Typing “owncloud” in a terminal gives me a memory error. Reinstalling either doesn’t help (via software center or apt-get) or doesn’t seem to work at all (with the commands on the instructions-page on the Owncloud homepage or the *.sh provided there. Adding the trusted key for the repository gives the following errors:

```
2022-05-18 13:40:57 URL:https://download.owncloud.com/desktop/ownCloud/stable/latest/linux/Ubuntu_22.04/Release.key [1412/1412] -> "-" [1]
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/isv:ownCloud:desktop.gpg'
gpg: Schlüsselblockhilfsmittel`(null)': Allgemeiner Fehler
gpg: Schlüssel 4ABE1AC7557BEFF9: 1 Beglaubigung wegen fehlendem Schlüssel nicht geprüft
gpg: Schlüssel D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 Beglaubigungen wegen fehlender Schlüssel nicht geprüft
gpg: Schlüssel 871920D1991BC93C: 1 Beglaubigung wegen fehlendem Schlüssel nicht geprüft
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 10
gpg:       ignorierte neue Schlüssel: 10
```

Another try, another error (from the owncloud forum thread):

"(https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-gpg-error-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified) then apt update and install owncloud-client."

This is what happens with the keys on my end:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.wrEBpIUG82/gpg.1.sh --keyserver https://download.owncloud.com/desktop/ownCloud/stable/latest/linux/Ubuntu_22.04/Release.key --recv-keys 4ABE1AC7557BEFF9
gpg: Schlüssel 0700205DFD41A71A: vom Import-Aufpasser zurückgewiesen
gpg: Anzahl insgesamt bearbeiteter Schlüssel: 1
```

I think this is the crux:

`gpg: Schlüssel 0700205DFD41A71A: vom Import-Aufpasser zurückgewiesen`

“Key … rejected by import watchdog”

Comment: I solved it by going to https://download.owncloud.com/desktop/ownCloud/stable/latest/linux/download/ and reinstall everything again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Owncloud doesn't like php8.1 (yet).  I finally got Owncloud running by installing php7.4 on Ubuntu 22.04. (I also installed php7.3 just to make sure).

Instructions on installing a previous version of PHP are [here](https://kifarunix.com/install-php-7-1-7-2-7-3-7-4-on-ubuntu-22-04/)
(make sure you read to the end of the instructions to set the default PHP version)

You'll need to also install PHP modules:

```
apt install -y libapache2-mod-php7.4 \
php7.4-apcu \
php7.4-mysql \
php7.4-intl \
php7.4-curl \
php7.4-json \
php7.4-gd \
php7.4-xml \
php7.4-mbstring \
php7.4-zip
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! Sadly, this didn't do it. I installed php 7.4 and 7.3 as well as the modules you mentioned. I set the standard version to 7.4, then tried 7.3. Owncloud still doesn't start. (When I activate the shortcut it shows up for about half a second in system monitor and then disappears again,)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the help of a nice commenter over at the owncloud forum!

I needed to add the repository key following this article:

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html

Now, there was a typo in one command, which the commenter spotted (after I tried without success to fix it myself):

> You are missing a space between the capital “O” and the dash that follows it.

(In the command with the caption "To download using wget and add such an OpenPGP key to your system, use:")

I'll repeat the link to the thread at owncloud:

https://central.owncloud.org/t/desktop-client-ubuntu-22-04-compatibility/37434/14

Cheers and thanks to anyone watching!

Comment: Thanks for the summary - I'm sure the solution is somewhere in there, but this whole installation process is so convoluted - couldn't get it to work in appreciable time. None of the links contains a straight forward solution - probably needs an hour work to get everything to install :/